# IntelliJ Plugin: Provide jar along with plugin and a quick fix to add dep. when jar-symbols are used in a project

Tags: java, intellij-plugin

I'd like to provide java custom annotations along with my plugin to analyse annotated code. There should be a something like a quick fix to add the missing dependencies to the project/module if these annotations are used there.

Any ideas/examples how to achieve this?

Thx